# Error : Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin YouTube iframe api

Tags: youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am getting 2 error in my console while using YouTube `iframe` API. 
First error

> Unrecognized feature: 'autoplay'.

In my code there is no auto play added. I don't know why this error showing
Second error

> Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/log/youtube: insecure reporting URL for secure page at character position 22. The default protections will be applied.

I don't know anything about this error
Third error

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://www.ytbooster.net').

I was add origin and widget_referrer in my code with this code and without this code error is still showing

```
   var player,
   time_update_interval = 0;

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
   player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    videoId: '<?= $vid ?>',
    playerVars: {
        color: 'white',
        controls: '0',
        disablekb: '1',
        rel: '0',
        origin: "http://www.ytbooster.net",
        widget_referrer: "http://www.ytbooster.net"


    },
    events: {
        onReady: initialize
    }
});
}
```